# Updating multiple Excel Sheets

Tags: excel, vba

I am creating an excel workbook with multiple different sheets. I want to be able to add a row to any sheet and have it reflected on the first sheet. I am having trouble with this since I want to add them to different sheets based on a condition. Is there any easy way to do this.

Comment: Unclear wording/needs more information. How should rows be reflected? should they update immediately or after running macro? what type of condition?
If you posted attempted code it would also help

Comment: The main sheet where I want each of the rows reflected is broken down in two sections submitted items and un submitted items. I want to be able to mark a row as submitted on a seperate sheet and have that row in the submitted half of the main work sheet. My biggest issue right now is how do I jump between sheets? I want this to happen every time I update one of the sheets.

Comment: "worksheets(index)" will let you jump between sheets.
For everything else, please spend more time to explain (ie pictures for how it should look)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a template for having multiple worksheets in VBA and setting values b/w them

```
Sub test ()
    Dim ws as worksheet
    Dim ws2 as worksheet
    Set ws = Worksheets(1)
    Set ws2 = Worksheets(2)

    ws2.Range("A") = ws.Range("A")
End Sub
```